# Phalcon use Phalcon\Tag OR Phalcon\Forms for creating forms

Tags: forms, phalcon

I searched up and down but couldn't find which one is better Phalcon\Tag OR Phalcon\Forms for creating forms.

Both classes have functionality to create form elements. But I found there are some handy tags in the Phalcon\Tag, for example Phalcon\Tag::emailField() or  Phalcon\Tag::dateField(array())

Phalcon documentation says:

> "*Phalcon\Forms is a component that aid the developer in the creation
>   and maintenance of forms in web applications.*"
>
> "*Phalcon\Tag is designed to simplify building of HTML tags. It
>   provides a set of helpers to generate HTML in a dynamic way.*"

Can anybody help me with the pros and cons of using both the methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In simple meaning Phalcon\Tag are used to design only html (users view). but for validation && adding rules to the form you need to use phalcon\forms i will show you an example of phalcon\forums below

NEW FORM CLASS:

```
use Phalcon\Forms\Form,
    Phalcon\Forms\Element\Password,
    Phalcon\Forms\Element\Email as Emailfield,
    Phalcon\Forms\Element\Check,
    Phalcon\Forms\Element\Hidden,
    Phalcon\Validation\Validator\PresenceOf,
    Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Identical,
    Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Email;

class LoginForm extends Form
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $email = new Emailfield('email', array(
            'placeholder' => 'Type your Email'
        ));
        $email->setLabel('E-Mail');
        $email->setFilters('email');
        $email->addValidators(array(
            new PresenceOf(array(
                'message' => 'E-mail is required'
            )),
            new Email(array(
                'message' => 'E-mail is not valid'
            ))
        ));

        $this->add($email);

        $password = new Password('password', array(
            'placeholder' => 'Type your Password'
        ));
        $password->setLabel('Password');
        $password->setFilters(array('striptags', 'string'));
        $password->addValidators(array(
            new PresenceOf(array(
                'message' => 'Password required'
            ))
        ));
        $this->add($password);

        //Remember
        $long_login = new Check('long_login', array(
            'value' => 'yes'
        ));
        $long_login->setLabel('Keep me logged in');
        $this->add($long_login);

        // CSRF
        $csrf = new Hidden('csrf');
        $csrf->addValidator(new Identical(array(
            'value' => $this->security->getSessionToken(),
            'message' => 'CSRF validation failed'
        )));
       // $this->add($csrf);

    }
}
```

In Controller:

```
$form = new LoginForm();
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (!$form->isValid($_POST)) {
        $errors = array();
        foreach ($form->getMessages() as $message) {
            $errors[] = $message;
        }
        if (!empty($errors))
            $this->flash->error(join('<br/>', $errors));
    } else {
        //Login Continues
    }
}


$this->view->setVar('form', $form);
```

To convert this form to html below is the code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.label('email',['class': 'control-label']) }}
        {{ form.render('email', ['class': 'form-control input-md']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.label('password',['class': 'control-label']) }}
        {{ form.render('password', ['class': 'form-control input-md']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        {{ form.render('long_login') }}
        {{ form.label('long_login') }}
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  One more thanks - I found that following the example is a better way to learn than following the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Really great example in general but I'm struggling with the flash message. After a quick google search I was more confused after reading the documentation. Some say that $this->flash->output() should be placed to the view to see the flash messages. Though this causes errors and I believe it's something from the past. Can somebody tell me what flash method should I place to view to see the flash messages or Where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: Well I managed to get \Phalcon\Flash\Session to work and I believe it's event more suitable for me than Direct. For that you need to register flash service in Dependency Injector in config/services.php. I also replaces classes with bootstrap classes.

```
$di->set('flash', function() {
    return new Phalcon\Flash\Session(array(
        'error'=>'text-danger',
        'warning'=>'text-warning',
        'notice'=>'text-info',
        'success'=>'text-success'                
    ));
});
```

Comment: In order to make that works you need to implement Bootstrap css and js,
because is in the array is only overwriting the class attribute inside you message DIV tag, tray something like this:``
$di->set('flash', function () {
    return new Flash(array(
        'error'   => 'alert alert-danger',
        'success' => 'alert alert-success',
        'notice'  => 'alert alert-info',
        'warning' => 'alert alert-warning'
    ));
});``

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which you are working.

If we say, you need to insert lots of data with lots of validations and it may change during progress then its far better to use "Phalcon\Forms"

As they are very dynamic.

Means you can change text-box with select box very easily without touching template.

You can add validations without worrying about template and other stuff.

And for-most reusable you can reuse form if you need.

so if there is less data then you are free to use anyone of that but more suggestible is "Phalcon\Forms" its very dynamic and structural.